# Javascript regex (negative) lookbehind not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox, regex-lookarounds

I need to modify the following javascript regex because the **negative lookbehind** in it throws an error in firefox:

```
content = content.replace(/(?![^<]*>)(?:[\"])([^"]*?)(?<!=)(?:[\"])(?!>)/g, '„$1“');
```

Does anyone have an idea and can help me out?

Comment: You just can move the `=` to the negated character class, `/(?![^<]>)"([^"=]?)"(?!>)/g`

Comment: Please vote for the issue in firefox at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1225665

Comment: @bradlis7 How do you vote? (It is quite a while since I logged in to bugzilla, but I still don't see a vote button. I did start following it - is that the same thing?) And this seems one of the few things that there is no shim for.

Comment: @DarrenCook After logging in, in the "Details Panel", It says "27 Votes [Vote]". It's a clunky UI, as you have to go to your vote page, check the issue and then submit.

Comment: Perhaps real soon now: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1634135

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**July 1, 2020 Update**

Starting with the ***FireFox 78 version***, `RegExp` finally supports lookbehinds, dotAll `s` flag, Unicode escape sequences and named captures, see the [Release Notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/78.0/releasenotes/):

> New [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) engine in SpiderMonkey, adding support for the dotAll flag, Unicode escape sequences, lookbehind references, and named captures.

Thank you very much, FireFox developers!!!

---

Lookbehinds are only available in browsers supporting ECMA2018 standard, and that means, only the latest versions of Chrome can handle them.

To support the majority of browsers, convert your pattern to only use lookaheads.

The `(?<!=)` negative lookbehind makes sure there is no `=` immediately to the left of the current location. `[^"]` is the atom that matches that character (note that `?` quantifier makes it optional, but `"` that is before `[^"]` can't be `=` and there is no need restricting that position).

So, you may use

```
content = content.replace(/(?![^<]>)"([^"=]?)"(?!>)/g, '„$1"');
                                      ^^^^^
```

Note that `(?:[\"])` is equal to `"`. `[^"=]?` matches 1 or 0 occurrences of a char other than `"` and `=`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PgrUio/2).

Comment: So this 2 regexes work the same, right?

Previous regex:
`(?![^<]*>)(?:[\"])([^"]*?)(?<!=)(?:[\"])(?!>)`

New regex:
`(?![^<]*>)"([^"=]*?)"(?!>)`

Comment: @Cla I wouldn't have posted if they were not.

Answer (score 2):

Lookbehind assertions are part of ES2018. They are not yet supported by firefox, that's why you're getting an error.

Chrome supports them since version [62](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4545&desc=2), and you can use them in Node.js >= 6.4 with the harmony flag, or in >= 9 without any flag.

You can check the proposal [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind) & browser support [here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/)

Comment: Do you know a workaround for this problem? I'm trying to rewrite the regex without the lookbehind but don't know how.

Comment: Post the text you want to match, and expected result, and we will be able to help you.

Comment: Still not supported in Firefox 69: https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind

Comment: Still not supported in Firefox 77.0.1 (64-bit). Yay progress!

Answer (score 2):

The exact equivalent of your regex `(?![^<]*>)"([^"]*?)(?<!=)"(?!>)`

without the lookbehind assertion is:

`(?![^<]*>)"((?:[^"=]+|=(?!"))*)"(?!>)`

Readable version

```
 (?! [^<]* > )
 "
 (                             # (1 start)
      (?:
           [^"=]+ 
        |  
           = 
           (?! " )
      )*
 )                             # (1 end)
 "
 (?! > )
```

Note this is not like your chosen answer, which is *not* an equivalent .

Comment: @EugeneBarsky  - Thanks for the typo fixes .

Answer (score 1):

2 years later, Firefox is finally catching up. ES2018 RegExp features will be included in FF78, due to be released end of June, 2020: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/78#JavaScript