# How to color only JSON keys via regex?

Tags: javascript, json, regex

In javascript, I want to capture all of my json keys via regex. Let's assume that the json outputs with every key-value pair in a new line. E.g.

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "age": 23,
}
```

In other words, every first instance of a string with double quotes.

Comment: `Object.keys(JSON.parse(jsonString))`? why thru regex approach?

Comment: Not sure a regular expression can hack it here. The JSON syntax is fairly complex. `"key \"name\""` is a valid key.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Text/values don't have color. Color is only useful if you want to display something somewhere. What are you displaying, how are you doing it and where are you displaying it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think regular expressions will cut it here, I would suggest you build an output string based off of your JSON:

```js
let json = {
  foo: "bar",
  age: 23,
  test1: 1,
  test2: 2,
  test3: 3,
};

let formattedJSONString = Object.entries(json)
  .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => `${acc}
    <span class='json-key'>"${key}": </span>
    <span class='value'>"${value}"</span>,<br/>`,
    `{<br/>`) + `}`;

document.write(formattedJSONString);
```

```css
.json-key {
  color: blue;
  margin-left: 8px;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.value {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you'd work it:

```
(?<=")    (.*?)    (?=":)
   1        2         3
```

1. Lookbehind to require a quote before the text you want.
2. What you actually want to capture.
3. Lookahead to require a quote and colon be present after your text.

Then, replace it with:

```
<span style="color: red;">$1</span>
```

[Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/BUUdoU/2)

Comment: Be careful with Lookbehind [lookbehind-not-working-in-firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011366/javascript-regex-negative-lookbehind-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: Don't forget to consider escaped quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I've used recursion for this.

JSON object

```
let json = {
  foo: "bar",
  age: 23,
  foo2: {
    hello: "world",
    world: "hello"
  },
};
```

This function will iterate over the JSON object and add its keys and values into span tags and seprate them with JSON syntax tokens

```js
let json = {
  foo: "bar",
  age: 23,
  hi: "bye",
  bar: {
    hi: "now",
    now: "hi"
  }
};

let stylizedJson = "<span class='syntax'>{</span><br/>" + createFormattedJSON(json,24) + "<br/><span class='syntax'>}</span>";

document.write(stylizedJson);

function createFormattedJSON(data, margin) {

  var formattedJson = '';

  Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    formattedJson += `<span style='margin-left:${margin}px;' class='json-key'>"${key}"</span><span class="syntax" ${this.scope}>:</span>`
    if (typeof value == "object") {
      formattedJson += `<span class='syntax'>{</span><br/>`
      formattedJson += this.createFormattedJSON(value, margin + 12)
      formattedJson += `<br/><span style='margin-left:${margin}px;' class='syntax'>}</span>`
    } else {
      if (Object.keys(data).reverse()[0] != key) formattedJson += `<span class='value'>"${value}"</span><span class="syntax">,</span><br/>`
      else
        formattedJson += `<span class='value'>"${value}"</span>`
    }
  })
  
  return formattedJson;
}
```

```css
.json-key {
  color: #7A01FF;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-family: Consolas;
}

.value {
  color: #F9D372;
  font-family: Consolas;
}

.syntax {
  color: #EEEEEE;
  font-family: Consolas;
}

body {
  background-color: #232932;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typescript/4.5.4/typescript.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks