# Regx look behind not support firefox

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox

I am trying to search if dash exist at start or the end of the string

It working fine for Chrome but unfortunately Firefox not yet support.

Here my regex code

```
/^(?!-)(?!.*--)[A-Za-z0-9-]+(?<!-)$/;
```

I expect on Firefox also catch when the word:

-test

test-

-test-

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript regex negative lookbehind not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011366/javascript-regex-negative-lookbehind-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: Yes similar problem but I am not so sure. how to understand that syntax and apply to my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate out the character set into two parts: one for (all but the last character) and one for (the last character), and then simply remove the `-` from the last character set:

```
/^(?!-)(?!.*--)[a-z\d-]*[a-z\d]$/i
```

(`[a-z\d]` with the case-insensitive flag is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9]` without the flag)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. And also optimize my synctax.

Comment: @MarkChhunlong: Note that this pattern can be written without lookarounds at all: `/^[a-z\d]+(?:-[a-z\d]+)*$/i`

Comment: or why not: `/^\b(?:[a-z\d]|-\b)+$/i` (shorter but less efficient).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thank you so much for your concern and provide the correct answer. I am less experience with regex and couldn't determine which one is the best solution.