# Regex to replace leading plus characters in query params (++, +- and +)?

Tags: javascript, regex, query-string, lunrjs

I am using [lunr.js](https://lunrjs.com/guides/searching.html).

This Javascript code below:

- gets the query parameters from the first search.
- replaces the binding + characters with spaces.
- stores the modified query in the search field for the next search.
- searches using the modified query.

```
var query = getUrlParameter('q');
var queryWithoutPlus = query.replace(/\+/g, " ");
searchField.value = queryWithoutPlus
index.search(queryWithoutPlus);
```

A query param string could look like `test+ABCD+Test++Test2+-Test+-Test+Test`.

The code above replaces the + characters in the query parameter `q` with spaces to display the result to the user in a nice manner,

Currently, a search string spaces

> "test +test -test"

currently results in

> "test  test -test"

What I need is:

> "test +test -test"

I tried to modify the resulting query multiple times using a tempQuery:

```
var tempQuery = query.replace(/\+\+/g, " -");
var queryWithoutPlus = tempQuery.replace(/\+\-/g, " -");
```

But this doesn't work out with the remaining + characters and doesn't feel correct.

Does it just boil down to using the correct regex (whatever it might be, advice welcome), or is there is even a better approach for using query parameters with lunr.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) query `(?<!\+)`

```
"test+ABCD+Test++Test2+-Test+-Test+Test".replace(/(?<!\+)\+/g, " ")
>> "test ABCD Test +Test2 -Test -Test Test"
```

As noted, this is not available on some browsers, like Microsoft's. In that case you need to replace with a temporary expression

```
"test+ABCD+Test++Test2+-Test+-Test+Test".replace(/\+\+/g, "#spaceplus#")
  .replace(/\+/g, " ").replace(/#spaceplus#/g, " +")
>> "test ABCD Test +Test2 -Test -Test Test"
```

Comment: Just fyi, I have tested this regex and it is not working in Internet Explorer, just in Chrome, maybe related to ECMA2018 support, see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011366 or the slash syntax.