# Why does this regex inculde square brackets in the results?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I rewrite the regex below so it won't return the square brackets in the results. I have to use match since it's part of other code. Can someone help?

```js
var s = '{[{main}(other data)][{data}(other data)][{address}(other data)]}';
m = 'data'
var qm = function(str) {
  return s.match(new RegExp('\\[{' + str + '}\\(.*?\\)\\]', 'gi'));
}
console.log(qm(m)); // returns "[{data}(other data)]" 
// trying to get "{data}(other data)" no square brackets
```

Comment: Why not just `substring(1, str.length - 1)`?

Comment: Can't add more code there. Have to redo the regex itself.

Comment: Then you can either group it and access the group `\\[({' + str + '}\\(.*?\\))\\]` or you can use lookarounds (lookbehind only works if using V8) `(?<=\\[){' + str + '}\\(.*?\\)(?=\\])`

Comment: [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) -> _"Return value: An Array whose contents depend on the presence or absence of the global (`g`) flag, or `null` if no matches are found. **If the `g` flag is used, all results matching the complete regular expression will be returned, but capturing groups will not.** If the `g` flag is not used, only the first complete match and its related capturing groups are returned."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match the brackets but not include them in the result.

```js
var s = '{[{main}(other data)][{data}(other data)][{address}(other data)]}';
m = 'data'
var qm = function(str) {
  return s.match(new RegExp('(?<=\\[){' + str + '}\\(.*?\\)(?=\\])', 'gi'));
}
console.log(qm(m)); // returns "[{data}(other data)]" 
// trying to get "{data}(other data)" no square brackets
```

Comment: Your answer throws error `SyntaxError: invalid regexp group`. Is this because of browser support?

Comment: That's possible, lookarounds are a new feature in JS regexp. It works in Chrome.

Comment: You're correct. It works in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011366/javascript-regex-negative-lookbehind-not-working-in-firefox